# React native Android Manifest permission setting with BLE

Tags: android, react-native, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I would using the react native to develop the mobile application
I need to using the application to connect the Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE)

I has some question about the Android permission setting on the AndroidManifest.xml and react native

1. If I have a old device, such as xiaomi mobile  is running Android 10 (sdk 28 or sdk 29),  do it is allow to use the bluetooth function or not ? I need to set the android:maxSdkVersion="30"  to lower?
2. Would any new permission are needed with Android 13 for the BLE.

I added the use permission on AndroidManifest.xml,

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" android:maxSdkVersion="30" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" android:maxSdkVersion="30" />

    
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT"
        android:usesPermissionFlags="neverForLocation"
        tools:targetApi="s" />

    <!-- Needed only if your app looks for Bluetooth devices. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN" />
    <!-- Needed only if your app makes the device discoverable to Bluetooth devices. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADVERTISE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
```

On the other hand, I would added a checking when I scan the device

```
  requestPermissionBluetoothConnectAndroid = async () => {
    const status = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
      PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT,
    );

    if (status === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
      return true;
    }

    if (status === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.DENIED) {
      ToastAndroid.show(
        'Location permission denied by user.',
        ToastAndroid.LONG,
      );
    } else if (status === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.NEVER_ASK_AGAIN) {
      ToastAndroid.show(
        'Location permission revoked by user.',
        ToastAndroid.LONG,
      );
    }
  };
```

However,  the application would be crashed when I scan the BLE devices

Comment: Take a look at this: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth/permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Bluetooth Scan permission must also be obtained from the user. I think this might be the reason why you are getting the error.

You must obtain Bluetooth and location permissions from the user as follows and check them before each scan;

```
  const handleAndroidPermissionCheck = async (cb: VoidCallback) => {
    if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
      const res = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
        PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
      );
      await PermissionsAndroid.requestMultiple([
        PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.BLUETOOTH_SCAN,
        PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT,
      ]);
      cb(res === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED);
    } else {
      cb(true);
    }
  };

  const startScan = () => {
    try {
      BleManager.scan([SERVICE_UUID], seconds, false).then(() => {});
    } catch (error) {}
  };
```

AndroidManifest should look like this;

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le" android:required="true" />
```

My build gradle is like this;

```
buildToolsVersion = "33.0.0"
minSdkVersion = 23
compileSdkVersion = 33
targetSdkVersion = 33
```